# Issues Creating WatermarkTextBox xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a custom Watermark Textbox in XAML for a windows phone App.  I have most things working.  If the Textbox is bound to a field with data, then the Watermark Text becomes invisible.  However, if the field starts out as empty and then I enter text in the control, I am not able to set the watermark as invisible.

I am listening for the TextChanged event, but in this case the Text property stays empty.  Any ideas?

```
 public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox
{
    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        this.TextChanged += WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged;

    }

    public string WatermarkText
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(WatermarkTextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(WatermarkTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "WatermarkText", typeof(string), typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public Visibility WatermarkTextVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)this.GetValue(WatermarkTextVisibilityProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(WatermarkTextVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkTextVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "WatermarkTextVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));



    void WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.WatermarkTextVisibility = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text) ? Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out my [Watermark Textbox For C#/XAML WinRT Apps](https://nuget.org/packages/WatermarkTextbox) on NuGet

If you want source then check out

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WatermarkTextBox/)

[Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/WatermarkTextBox/WatermarkTextBox.cs)

Please not above links opens only CS file, you may need theme for it so check out generic.xaml file in repo.

Comment: Do you have the source code available anywhere.  When I install the nuget package, I only get the dll.  I would like to know what I need to do to fix this for any future applications.